# I don't understand how many file,i have to create

Tags: encryption

Implement the Caesar Cipher algorithm to encrypt and decrypt a file contents using C language. The cipher basic all use algorithm . Your program should have two C files named encrypt.c and decrypt.c that contains encrypt() and decrypt() functions correspondently for the purpose. In the encryption.c file, use the main() function to take input from a “input.txt” file and store the encrypted message to “enc_msg.txt” file. In the decryption.c file, use the main() function to take input from a “enc_msg.txt” file and store the decrypted message to “dec_msg.txt” file and print the decrypted message in console output as well. The key is 3.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Two Files ("encrypt.c" and "decrypt.c") for your program and one file with the plaintext ("input.txt). The “enc_msg.txt” is created by your encrypt function and the “enc_msg.txt” by the decrypt function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two .c files encrypt.c and decrypt.c
2. Create sample data input.txt file
3. Run your encrypt program to create output file enc_msg.txt from input.txt file
4. Run your decrypt program to create output file dec_msg.txt from input enc_msg.txt file

So you need to **create 3 files** encrypt.c decrypt.c and input.txt

And running your programs will generate two more files enc_msg.txt and dec_msg.txt